# $P(N|n)$ given $P(n|N)$ and $\overline {N}$

Tags: quantum-information, probability

This is one of the exercises of Barnett's book on [quantum information](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/quantum-information-9780198527626?cc=it&lang=en&).

A particle counter records counts with an efficiency $\eta$. This means that each particle is detected with probability $\eta$ and missed with probability $1-\eta$. Let $N$ be the number of particles present and $n$ be  the number of detected. 
Then:
\begin{equation}
P(n|N)=\frac{N!}{n!(N-n)!}\eta^n (1-\eta)^{N-n}
\end{equation}

I know the mean number of particle present is:

\begin{equation}
\bar{N}=\sum N P(N)
\end{equation}

I want to calculate $P(N|n)$. I'm stuck here by a while, so I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: Use [Bayes's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem).

Comment: Yes, but how do you find P(n) in order to have a mathematical expression for P(N|n)?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: @petrolio. It doesn't matter, because it just ends up as a normalization constant, which means you can calculate what it needs to be after you have applied Bayes' theorem